# Regular expression for IPAddress or hostname validation

Tags: javascript, regex

validation need to allow 3 ipaddress or hostname seperated with comma or more than 3 ipaddress or hostname  with comma

Allow 
Test 1 -> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Test 2 -> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

no need vaildate the ipaddress, Only validate the seperated by comma and the ipaddress 3 times or more than 3 times

I tried

```
var hostSeperatorComma = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\,[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\,[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.][\,a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*$/;

if (!hostSeperatorComma.test(hosts)) {
// return 'invaild host';
}
```

I know i did a mistake in last part, but i don't know to solve it
Please share your idea to help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.  There are 42000 questions that validate IP addresses and email aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex I believe:

```
var hostSeperatorComma = /^(?:[\w.-]+,){2,}[\w.-]+$/;
```